# Выделение и копирование текста в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, copy

Есть код для копирования текста в буфер обмена по клику на фрагменте текста. Все работает, только не получается добавить надпись "Скопировано" после копирования.

```js
function selectText(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) { // IE
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text" onclick="selectText('text')">Copy some text</div>
```

Пробовал добавлять строку `$(#text).text('Copied')` не работает. Подскажите, как можно реализовать вывод уведомления. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function selectText(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) { // IE
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
  $('#text').text('Copied'); // <---
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" onclick="selectText('text')">Copy some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.execCommand` [устарел](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), замените на
`window.navigator.clipboard.writeText(...text...)`